# Who gave Ayatul-Kursi that appellation?

Tags: terminology, surat-al-baqarah, ayah

Who named, or first called, [Ayatul-Kursi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Baqara_255), *Ayatul-Kursi*?  Of course, it's the Verse of the Throne. But who actually choose to call it by that name?

> Allah - there is no deity except Him, the Ever-Living, the Sustainer of [all] existence. Neither drowsiness overtakes Him nor sleep. To Him belongs whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on the earth. Who is it that can intercede with Him except by His permission? He knows what is [presently] before them and what will be after them, and they encompass not a thing of His knowledge except for what He wills. His Kursi extends over the heavens and the earth, and their preservation tires Him not. And He is the Most High, the Most Great. -- [Qur'an 2:255](https://quran.com/2/255)

Answer (score 3):

Due to the high names of Allah in this ayah, the name Ayatul Kursi was taken by people in the Prophet's lifetime. And nobody is known accurately who named this ayah.

From the book Tafsir Al-Mizan:

> This verse was named "the verse of the Chair(Ayatul Kursi)" in the early period of Islam during the lifetime of the Prophet; and was thus described by the Prophet himself as the traditions quoted from him and the Imams of Ahlu'l-bayt and the companions prove. That this verse was given a special name shows how much importance was attached to it. It could only be because of the highest nobility of its meaning and the elegance and grace of its style.
>
> Source: [here](http://www.shiasource.com/al-mizan/tafsir/2-255/)

You can go to this book and learn more:

- Tafsir al-Mizan, Vol.2, page 514-515, Allamah Muhammad Hussein
  Tabatabai.

Comment: Answers which solely contain quotes from elsewhere and no possible self-explanation and analysis which directly addresses the question are considered low-quality. So please provide your own explanation as well along with the quote as a reference. [Do we want cut-and-paste answers?](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/324)

Comment: Sure I got it! Will try it